# How to merge two columns into rows and repeat other columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, merge, powerquery

I have data in excel like below

| Name1 | Name2 | Number | address | arrival_time | checked_NLP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | bcd | 1 | 11AA | 00:10:10 | yes |
| cde | abc | 2 | 22BB | 00:10:05 | yes |
| bcd | def | 3 | 33CC | 00:10:15 | NO |

i want it like below

| Name | Number | address | arrrival_time | checked_NLP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 11AA | 00:10:10 | yes |
| bcd | 1 | 11AA | 00:10:10 | yes |
| abc | 2 | 22BB | 00:10:05 | yes |
| cde | 2 | 22BB | 00:10:05 | yes |
| bcd | 3 | 33CC | 00:10:15 | NO |
| def | 3 | 33CC | 00:10:15 | NO |

how can i merge two columns into one and then repeat the other columns for the merged column values.

Comment: You tagged excel-2007 and excel-2010 which version of the two are you using (or maybe even a different?). Also, would power query be an option?

Comment: i dont think version is an issue, any version is ok, also power query is ok as long as it solve the problem. i need to merge name1 and name2 and based on that data needs to repeat. how can we do that in power query ?

Comment: If version is no issue don't tag older versions, but tag the one you use. Older versions have limitations. I recommend tagging power query, this should be fairly easy there. I'm visiting this site on my mobile mainly, so somebody else should be able to help you in power query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple 2 step method in powerquery

Click select the two name columns, right click, Merge Columns ... using a colon separator

[image]

Click select the new merged column, right click, Split Column ..  By Delimiter ... each occurrence, into rows

[image]

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Source,{"Name1", "Name2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Merged Columns", {{"Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Merged")
in  #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(r,A2:F4,
     HSTACK(
            TOCOL(TAKE(r,,2)),
            INDEX(r,
                  INT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(r)*2,,,0.5)),
                  SEQUENCE(1,4,3))))
```

This does the trick in Office 365 by formula.

`TOCOL` transposes the first two columns to row, row by row.

The the remaining 4 columns are indexed and the rows are repeated, so they match the `TOROW` solution.

Comment: you might need to fix the formula: `=LET(p,A2:F4,b,TOCOL(TAKE(p,,2)),HSTACK(b,INDEX(p,INT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(p)*2,,,0.5)),SEQUENCE(1,4,3))))`

Comment: Because of `TAKE(r,-4)` this one instead it should be `r` as your column starts from `3` please check in the last `SEQUENCE()`

Comment: I actually had my `scan by column` argument set to TRUE instead of keeping it to the default. Thanks, good catch

Comment: Yeah not just `Scan By Column` but also the `TAKE(r,-4)` it took only last 4 rows, however i fixed it. and no thanks. Your solutions helps to learn new things as well, thank to you and this great community.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the last response is totally correct and meets your needs. The first step is to merge these two columns with any delimiter, such as a colon, and then in the second step, perform the splitting.

To do this, you can click on the 'Advanced Options' menu and then select 'Split into Rows.' This will convert your 3-row dataset into six rows.

I hope you have already completed these steps.

Thank you